# Make use of second hard drive provided by host

Tags: centos, partition, ssd

I have purchased a dedicated server from nocix - `AMD Quadcore 120SSD + 2TB Preconfigured`

It is running `CentOS 6.8` and I have installed `apache 2.2`, `mysql 5.6` and `php 7.0.14`.

I have run out of space on the main 120GB SSD and I am trying to mount the 2TB drive on to a new folder. I am completely new to dedicated servers and have only ever used shared hosting with cpanel.
Basically I have partitioned the 2TB drive as a single partition so it was `/dev/sdb` and I now have `/dev/sdb1`, after formatting I created the dir /newdrive and tried this command: `mount /dev/sdb1 /newdrive`

I then got the error: `error writing /etc/mtab.tmp: No space left on device`

I have no idea what is going on or how to fix it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are completely out of space on your first drive, so not even mounting the new drive will help. You need to make some space available on the old drive by deleting files from somewhere - the `/tmp` directory and other temp space (e.g. `/var/tmp`, `/var/spool`) would be the first place I would look to clean up. Once you have even just a little bit of space available, you can then mount the new drive with the same command you're trying to use.

Please note that if you're using multiple partitions, you will need to free up space in the partition containing `/etc`, which may be different from the partition(s) containing the temp spaces I referenced above.

Comment: Ok I managed to free up 30GB. I need to use the 2TB drive on a users home directory that I've created /home1/username/ which already has 60GB of files on it, can I just mount the second drive to it using the command mount? would this affect the files already in this folder?

Comment: It will mask out the files already in the folder, and you would have to add the mount specification to `/etc/fstab` in order to have it mounted every time the system restarted. You can copy the files to the new drive by mounting the new drive at `/newdrive`, then changing where it's mounted, but you will also have to be sure to set the correct ownership on the directory after you've mounted it in the correct place.

Comment: Worked a charm, I first mounted the drive to /newdrive -> copied the files from /home1 to /newdrive -> deleted the files from /home1 -> then mounted the drive to /home1. Down to 7% used space on the SSD and about 5% on the HDD so thanks for the help!